# How to list CUDA devices in windows 7 using cmd?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-7, cuda, gpgpu

How to display as a list CUDA availible devices in windows 7 using command line?

Do I need to install additional software to do this?

Comment: One of the example programs in the CUDA SDK will do this for you.

Comment: One of the utility programs supplied in the CUDA driver package will also do this for you

Answer (score 12):

In directory `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI` there is an utility `nvidia-smi.exe` it can query lots of different stats about your GPUs. To list all GPUs in your system run it with `-L` option.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to compile and execute the **deviceQuery** example.[deviceQuery source here](https://github.com/pathscale/nvidia_sdk_samples/blob/master/deviceQuery/1_Utilities/deviceQuery/deviceQuery.cpp)

nvidia-smi command line tool (it comes with CUDA installation) is also a very useful.
It shows you information regarding the GPUs used, the current load of each of them (memory/power/cores), and the processes that are running on CUDA.
Take a look at the following for as an example:

```
Tue Apr  7 12:56:41 2015       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 346.46     Driver Version: 346.46         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           On   | 0000:05:00.0     Off |                  Off |
| N/A   32C    P8    26W / 149W |     56MiB / 12287MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla K80           On   | 0000:06:00.0     Off |                  Off |
| N/A   29C    P8    29W / 149W |     56MiB / 12287MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```